# get last id number on json array javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a sample json array that contains a list of employeeId's

`[{"employeeId": "20180000002"},{"employeeId": "20180000001"},{"employeeId":"20180000003"},{"employeeId": "20180000000"}]`

wanted to get the last id which is `employeeId":"20180000003`

```
$.ajax({
    url:'api/applicants/getwatchers',
    type:'GET',
    success: function(data){
        watcherId = (data[data.length-1].employeeId || watcherId);
        newWatcherId = parseInt(watcherId) + 1;
        console.log(watcherId);

    }
});
```

but the console.log was `employeeId": "20180000000`

Comment: The last id is `20180000000`, `20180000003` is second to the last.

Comment: You mean the highest id?

Comment: `(data[data.length-1].employeeId || watcherId)` will give you the last element of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> wanted to get the last id which is employeeId":"20180000003

By *last id*, if you meant *largest id* (generated last by the system), then use `Math.max.apply` and `map`

```
var arr = [{"employeeId": "20180000002"},{"employeeId": "20180000001"},{"employeeId":"20180000003"},{"employeeId": "20180000000"}];
watcherId = Math.max.apply( null, arr.map( s => +s.employeeId ) );
```

`watcherId` is already a `Number`, no need to do `parseInt`, so the newWatcherId becomes

```
newWatcherId = watcherId  + 1;
```

Comment: With ES6, you can do: `watcherId = Math.max(...arr.map(s => s.employeeId));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the array before you grab the last element if you want to get the largest number.

```
$.ajax({
url:'api/applicants/getwatchers',
type:'GET',
success: function(data){
    data.sort((a,b) => b.employeeId - a.employeeId)
    watcherId = (data[data.length-1].employeeId || watcherId);
    newWatcherId = parseInt(watcherId) + 1;
    console.log(watcherId);

}
});
```

It's possible I got the sort backwards - I always do that haha. In which case try:

```
data.sort((a,b) => a.employeeId - b.employeeId)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array in descending order and then get the first one as shown below:

```
list = [{"employeeId": "20180000002"},{"employeeId": "20180000001"},{"employeeId":"20180000003"},{"employeeId": "20180000000"}];
sortedIds = list.map(emp => emp.employeeId) // map the array to empIds.
    .sort((a, b) => b - a)[0];              // sort desc.
lastId = sortedIds[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.max()` on the array of `employeeId` using the spread operator.

```
var maxId = Math.max(...data.map(el=>el. employeeId)); // Will give you the max ID
watcherId = (maxId || watcherId);
newWatcherId = parseInt(watcherId) + 1;
console.log(watcherId);
```